# Integration Question with Root at the Bottom

Tags: integration

Can anyone please give me a clue to solving this questions. I have tried substituting $x = \sqrt{\mathrm{tan}\ u}$ but then I get a root at the bottom which I can't get rid off. Also I have tried tan x but that isn't any better.

$$\int \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}\ dx$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: try $t=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I tried that but I get the exact same integral again